# Google Analytics Embed API: Get property ID from variable with client url

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have tried to search for an answer on here but couldn't quite find one that has exactly the answer I need.

So, we're a web agency and we have built a little portal where our clients can manage their web design needs with us and we wanted to include an embedded Google Analytics view for their sites traffic.

I've managed to embed the Google Analytics and it works nicely, the Oauth flow works client side, which is fine :) But now I just have a dilemma, many of my clients have several sites on their GA profiles.

When my clients register for our service, they give me their site url which I store as a PHP variable that I use for various other things on their dashboards. Since I already have the site url stored as a variable, is there a way in one of the Google API's to use that url that would return the 'id' of the GA property associated with that url?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Via the management api you could query either the [web property](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties#resource) or a [view](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles#resource); both the property and the view resource contain a web url property, so you could iterate through their properties/views and find the matching Url to your clients website.

Caveat is that the field does not need to be filled correctly for GA to work, so if they have entered a wrong value without noticing the above will not work.

If I understand you correctly  your problem is that you have access to more/other accounts than you need. The obvious solution would be that your client authorizes you only for the relevant properties (after all the permission system allows to set permissions at the view level).